# Validation for changes on textfield in Extjs

Tags: extjs3

In my UI, I have a gridpanel and 'add' button. when you click the add button, an add window will appear with a few textfields to be filled in. Under in my add window, I have a button 'save' and 'close' at the bottom part. Now, whenever I filled in a data in my textfields and accidentally click the close button, I want to have a prompt message that saying 'there are data that haven't save yet' but if there's no changes, it will close automatically without prompting message.

```
 text: 'Close',
 handler:function(){

     //...I believe this is where I have to put my code.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isDirty() method. Form components has this method available. It returns true or false.

> Ext.getCmp('textfield1').isDirty();